Stepping into library's or .NET code while debuging with Visual Studio Code
I want to step into a library's or .NET code while debugging. But it always skips the lines when a function calls into implementation that is not in my project source files.
I am using .NET 6
Apart from default launch.json settings I added an option in launch.json "justMyCode":false
Also every similar SO question I find is either about .NET framework or Visual Studio.

Libraries do not, in general, include debug information in their released versions, so you cannot step into them.

@OldBoy understood, sorry if my question is uninformed, I am coming from a perspective where this is (almost) default functionality of Visual Studio 2022.
